# Unable to import term sets from CSV in sharepoint 2010

Tags: csv, sharepoint, import, set

I'm unable to import a term set using CSV in SharePoint 2010. I get the following error:
**An error was encountered while attempting to import the term set at line [last line] of the submitted file and some data may not have been cleaned up. Please ensure that this file is a valid csv file and adheres to the correct format as in the sample file ImportTermSet.csv**

I've tried re-using the sample file itself to create my term set, creating the term set in Notepad (+ensuring that it is a UTF-8 CSV), but all in vain :(
Could some one please help me here?

Answer (score 0):

http://blog.jussipalo.com/2011/04/sharepoint-importing-term-set-gives.html

Comment: Please summarize the answer here instead of just linking to it. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers

Answer (score 0):

For the record: all repeating instances of terms must have exactly the same case.

Example

```
,,,TRUE,,Continent,Political Entity,,,,,
,,,TRUE,,continent,Political Entity,Country,,,,
,,,TRUE,,Continent,Political Entity,Country,Province or State,,,
```

The above will fail because level 1 term "Continent" has a lower case "c" on the second row.

Answer (score 0):

Take attention to how nesting level are declared.

this is an example of an CORRECT CSV file (make attention on order of nested levels)

```
"Term Set Name","Term Set Description","LCID","Available for Tagging","Term Description","Level 1 Term","Level 2 Term","Level 3 Term","Level 4 Term","Level 5 Term","Level 6 Term","Level 7 Term"
"My Term Set","Description of My Term Set",,"True",,,,,,,,
,,,"True",,"Italy",,,,,,
,,,"True",,"Italy","Venice",,,,,
,,,"True",,"France",,,,,,
,,,"True",,"France","Paris",,,,,
,,,"True",,"Germany","Berlin",,,,,
```

this is an example of an INCORRECT CSV file:

```
"Term Set Name","Term Set Description","LCID","Available for Tagging","Term Description","Level 1 Term","Level 2 Term","Level 3 Term","Level 4 Term","Level 5 Term","Level 6 Term","Level 7 Term"
"My Term Set","Description of My Term Set",,"True",,,,,,,,
,,,"True",,"Italy",,,,,,
,,,"True",,"Italy","Rome",,,,,
,,,"True",,"France","Paris",,,,,
,,,"True",,"France",,,,,,
```

LAST LINE WILL GIVE IMPORT ERROR SINCE "FRANCE" ALREADY EXISTS!!!